# How to apply effect to a bitmap instead of a visual control?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I would like to apply `TContrastEffect` to a `Bitmap` instead of a `TControl`. Is there any way I can follow to do this? Right now I must create a `TControl`, put `TContrastEffect` as child of this control, assign this control to a form, paint the bitmap on the surface of this control and then I can do `MyBitmapWithEffect := aControl.makeScreenShot` but I think it's not very efficient and maybe there is a way to directly apply the effect to the bitmap

Comment: Per the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Applying_FireMonkey_Image_Effects): "*An effect has a visual result **only if it is the child of a visual component**. You can apply effects over any 2D component.*"  So no, you cannot use FMX effect components on bitmaps directly. But you can load the bitmap into a `TImage`, apply effects as needed, and then grab a screenshot of it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I m sure we can apply the effect directly on a bitmap, because if you look the delphi source code, the effect is even store in a bitmap (FEffectBitmap in TControl). In some way the screenshot it's just the painting on a bitmap so why it's not possible to paint directly on the bitmap ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: maybe we must use procedure ProcessEffect(const Canvas: TCanvas; const Visual: TBitmap; const Data: Single); virtual; but not uderstand yet what is const Data: Single

Comment: "*why it's not possible to paint directly on the bitmap?*" - because the Effects framework is not designed to be used that way. It is designed to be used with visual controls only. The fact that a bitmap is used internally is an *implementation detail*, and you don't have access to call that internal logic for drawing effects on your own bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

uses FMX.Filter.Effects;

```
var
  Filter: TFilterContrast;
begin
  Filter := TFilterContrast.Create(nil);
  Filter.Input := Image1.Bitmap;
  Filter.Contrast := 1.5;
  Image1.Bitmap := Filter.Output;
end;
```

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.